# Different ways that data of tables can be physically organised on disk

Tags: database, disk, database-table

Can anyone help me with this please?

What are some of the different ways that the data of tables can be physically organised on disk?

Comment: Any each way that means they can be written to and retrieved. Is this your homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different types of file organization the most populars

Heap file
Sorted File
Hashed File